# filter adapter with regex

Tags: android, regex, filter, android-listview

I have implemented a listview and an editbox that filters the data in listview. I use

```
myAdapter.getFilter().filter(txt);
```

It works fine when txt contains the char sequence from the beginning of my data.
E.g. for value "This is my value" and filtering "value" it passes the filter, but when I delete 'v' and filtering text is 'alue' the filter removes it from adapter.

Is there a way (except implementing my own filter) to filter by regex or something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with "full match" vs. "partial match" semantics.

1. You could try a leading `.*`.
2. You could play with an anchor like `^`.